# Adding new Table Data <td> after the 3rd element of <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I've encountered some problems while building something, I want my application to become modular so the modules are all independent and I can simply activate and deactivate them. I have this table

```
<tbody>

    <tr data-id="">
        <td><input name="id[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        <td>

            <a title="Edit" href="/post/update/">
            <i class="icon-edit"></i></a> &nbsp; 
            <a title="Remove" href="/post/remove/" class="text-danger remove"><i class="icon-remove" value=""></i></a>

        </td>
        <td>53b1098726ea03181ef607a4</td>
        <td>Test post</td>
        <td>draft</td>
        <td valign="middle">June 30, 2014 02:59 PM</td>
    </tr>   

    <tr data-id="">
        <td><input name="id[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        <td>

            <a title="Edit" href="/post/update/">
            <i class="icon-edit"></i></a> &nbsp; 
            <a title="Remove" href="/post/remove/" class="text-danger remove"><i class="icon-remove" value=""></i></a>

        </td>
        <td>53b255006f9f65c426433158</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>draft</td>
        <td valign="middle">July 01, 2014 02:16 PM</td>
    </tr>   

    <tr data-id="">
        <td><input name="id[]" value="" type="checkbox" class="form-control"></td>
        <td>

            <a title="Edit" href="/post/update/">
            <i class="icon-edit"></i></a> &nbsp; 
            <a title="Remove" href="/post/remove/" class="text-danger remove"><i class="icon-remove" value=""></i></a>

        </td>
        <td>53b3a3fbac4e617822fa82ed</td>
        <td>this is an example post with category</td>
        <td>draft</td>
        <td valign="middle">July 02, 2014 02:31 PM</td>
    </tr>   

</tbody>
```

and then I have this jQuery:

```
var post_table_body = $('body .post-list .table tbody tr');

// append the table-content
$.each(post_table_body, function(key, item) {
    console.log(item.children);
    item.children().after('<td>Sample Category</td>');
    //item.children().eq(3).after('<td>Sample</tb>');
});
```

so basically what I wanted to do is add an additional `<td>` after the 3rd `<td>`
but I'm having this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

whenever I try to run it on my browser, can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('body .post-list .table tbody tr').each(function(){
$(this).find('td:eq(3)').after('Your String').
});
```

Comment: wow it worked! I was wondering.. can you please explain why I got the problem? And how this one works? thank you so much.. so I can note it :D

Comment: @AlleoIndong reason is you are not targeting children `td`

Comment: ohhh as I expected but when I `console.log` it seems like it was selected correctly >_< thank you so much again

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
// append the table-content
$.each(post_table_body, function() {
   $('<td>Sample Category</td>').insertAfter($(this).find('td:nth-child(3)'));
});
```